Как в Astra Linux подписать файлы для замкнутой программной среды
Есть Астра Линукс 1.7.5
На ней включен режим "замкнутой программной среды"
У меня есть два официальных ключа
***.gpg
***.key
Всё установил согласно иструкции https://wiki.astralinux.ru/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1212431
Публичный ключ "***.gpg" копировал в /etc/digsig/keys
Для теста использовал бинарник ffmeg
Подписал его этой командой
bsign -N -s --pgoptions="--default-key=00000000000000000000000000000 --passphrase-file=/opt/password" /opt/ffmpeg
Проверил bsign -w /opt/ffmpeg
Ругани нет...
id: bsign v1.0
hash: {GOST R34.11-2012} 000000000000000000000000000
signature_size: 000
signature:
   ...(наверное лучше скрыть)
signer: 000000000000
timestamp: 31 Jul 2024 13:00:01 (1722420001)
bsign: good hash found in '/opt/ffmpeg'
version: 1
id: bsign v1.0
xattr hash: {GOST R34.11-2012} 0000000000000000000000000000
xattr signature_size: 000
xattr signature:
   ...(наверное лучше скрыть)
signer: 0000000000
timestamp: 31 Jul 2024 13:00:01 (1722420001)
bsign: good xattr hash found in '/opt/ffmpeg'

Запускаю его просто дёргая из консоли /opt/ffmpeg
В это время в системном журнале такое сообщение
Jul 31 14:27:39 astra1759 kernel: DIGSIG:[ERROR]  digsig_gost_bsign_verify: ERROR, signer key was not found (ID=0x4cXXXXXX)
Jul 31 14:27:39 astra1759 kernel: DIGSIG:[ERROR]  VERIFICATION FAILED: path=/opt/ffmpeg uid=0 gid=0

Что я делаю не так? Я так понимаю файлы подписались нормально, но нет какого то сертификата\ключа на устройстве для сверки подписи.
Как избавиться от ошибки?

вместо 00000000000000000000000000000 нужно наверное отпечаток подписи поставить

После установки ключа в /etc/digsig/keys или /etc/digsig/xattr_keys надо вызывать update-initramfs -u -k all, ибо парсек тащит ключи из ramdisk'a. И потом ребут, потом проверять подпись.
